# How to parse Curl response?

Tags: php, curl

I am able to send the `GET` request and receive the response at following line.

```
 $curl_resp = curl_exec($curl);
```

I used the following to parse the response, but it does not work, I have manually set some values to `$curl_resp` but still not sure how to access the value of each tag of the `xml` separately.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($curl_resp);
```

**NOTE:**  I recevice the actual xml but cant parse it, (*I need to get each tag's value separately in a variable*)

**Code:**

```
<?php

   $service_url = ' The Url goes here';
   $curl = curl_init($service_url);
   $curl_post_data = array(
        "PASSWORD" => 'pass',
        "USERNAME" => 'username'
        );
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
   $curl_resp = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
```

Comment: will u post ur whole code?

Comment: is the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option set?

Comment: Not enough information provided (for eg: source code), can't help you OP.

Comment: Are you able to see any data when doing print_r/echo/etc?

Comment: OP, what's the entire XML file look like (that you retrieved from the third-party server)

Comment: @DavidHarris, the whole code is updated now please remove your down vote thanks

Comment: @rOcKiNgRhO, the whole code is updated now

Comment: see this function http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php#105697

Answer (score 2):

Your variable `$curl_response` is different than `$curl_resp` (*what you're trying to parse*)

You can access the value of each tag just like any other array.

Comment: @Pankit Kapadia, The xml that I am parsing using simplexml is a sample, I need to parse the response of the web service ($curl_resp)

Comment: @Pankit Kapadia **DO NOT** add meaningless formatting-only changes to people's posts.  Doing so is an abuse of the suggested edit system.

Comment: Thanks Charles... These minor edits for rep are starting to get really irritating.

Comment: @Charles - Thanks for the suggestion but i don't think its meaningless. code should be look like `code`. Thats what i am trying to do, nothing more then that.

Comment: @PankitKapadia, you also added silly italics.  Don't.  You made no substantial improvement to the post at all, period, bottom line.  Knock it off.

Comment: @Charles - i agree that silly italics was not needed. but its not bad as it is ryt nw. needed 6 characters to be edited.:) I am not opposing you bro and i think the `code` formatting is substantial. Its not as bad as you are saying.

Comment: @Charles - and of course sorry for talking to you like this :) i always respect seniors.

Answer (score 1):

if the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option is not set then your `$curl_resp` will just return `true/false`.

if it is set you may be returning `false` or a poorly formed `xml string`. If you post more code or the actual curl response text we may be able to provide more info.

EDIT:

upon reading the code looks like you are assigning the response text to $curl_response instead of $curl_resp

Comment: yes does that make any difference? when I print the curl_response it shows the response as a string output. I will rename it but how to access the value of each tag!!?

Comment: you appear to be using the correct syntax but without seeing your xml string I cannot tell if all is correct

Comment: Is there any way to put the response in something like an array to be more accessible?

Comment: this may help you http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php

there is no need to convert to an array because the object you have is just as simple

Answer (score -1):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "your url");    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Googlebot/2.1 (+http://www.google.com/bot.html)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```